# Table Data display not appropriate at mobile and tablet device

Tags: html, css, html-table, vertical-alignment, responsive

Everything works fine at desktop version, when it goes to the tablet/mobile, the vertical align display more on the top.

They have the same css :

```
th, td {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 3%;
    font-size: 14px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

html:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td >Displacement</td>
        <td>4410 c.c. </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Rated H.P.</td>
        <td>86ps/ 2400 rpm</td>
    </tr>
        <tr> 
        <td>Max torque</td>
        <td>222ft-lb/ 1400 rpm</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Available for</td>
        <td>FD40/45/50</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i checked in mobile and tablet using your code, it looks all fine. can you be more specific about your question. what font are you using and all the css codes that you are using on the page. it would be more easy to answer if you could show the demo on codePen or something.

Comment: Thanks for reply, the problem had solved. I remove the fonts when i want to upload to web server, and then its centered. 

The font is the problem.

Comment: yes, most of the time font will be problem so i asked what font you used :)

Comment: and please don't forget to mark "best answer" so that the post will be closed :)